# Forward_messages как переслать сообщение из сторонней группы определенному пользователю в чате бота?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon, python-telegram-bot

Имеется грабер, который из стороннего чата записывает все объявления в БД (chanal_id, message_id, price)
Имеется пользователь который в боте задает диапазон цены нужных ему объявлений (сохраняется в БД user_id, price)

Что у меня не получается: Пересылать пользователю в ЧАТ БОТА сообщения из стороннего чата.

Пересылка получается от личного имени, как от юзера, а не как от бота.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient


with TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    data = client.forward_messages(to_username, message_id/s, from_chanal)
```

Если вместо phone ввожу username_bot, то выдает ошибку

```
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.MessageIdInvalidError: The specified message ID is invalid or you can't do that operation on such message (caused by ForwardMessagesRequest)
```

Python 3.10

Telethon 1.28.5

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я понял что это не возможно.
Какие варианты обхода я нашел:

1. Копировать все сообщение в БД и копировать юзернэйм отправителя и отправлять из чат бота сообщение : сообщение от юзер_1234  - такое
2. Отправлять сообщение как ссылку(если это не приватный канал), в формате t.me/chat_name/message_id